# Can you combine phpunit "exactly" and "at" calls?

Tags: phpunit

I have a mocked class I'm using in a test and I am looking for a way to simultaneously ensure that a single method is called exactly twice and with different arguments each call. My code is something like:

```
$mocked->expects($this->at(0))->method('mockedMethod')->with($this->equalsTo(123);
$mocked->expects($this->at(1))->method('mockedMethod')->with($this->equalsTo(456);
```

I'd like an assertion failure if a third call is made to mockedMethod, regardless of argument.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party but hopefully this helps someone who is looking.  Yes, you can combine at() and exactly().  In your example it would look something like the following:

```
$mocked->expects($this->at(0))->method('mockedMethod')->with($this->equalsTo(123);
$mocked->expects($this->at(1))->method('mockedMethod')->with($this->equalsTo(456);
$mocked->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('mockedMethod');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
require_once 'SomeClass.php';

class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnArgumentStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->returnArgument(0));

        // $stub->doSomething('foo') returns 'foo'
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething('foo'));

        // $stub->doSomething('bar') returns 'bar'
        $this->assertEquals('bar', $stub->doSomething('bar'));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this test in fact tests nothing

Comment: I've provided an example of what he's trying to accomplish, I'm assuming a developer can connect the dots from there.  Also, this test has a mocked class, an expectation, and two assertions... how exactly does this "test nothing"?   BTW, this test comes straight from PHPUnit documentation so are you saying the people that make PHPUnit are wrong?  LOL

Comment: I'm responding to your comment and down vote, and very clearly am disputing your claim that the PHPUnit test displayed as an example for this question, which comes straight out of the official PHPUnit documentation, does in fact test something.  All the drama is just you.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.